# Private PyPI containing package with same name

Tags: python, dependencies, pip, pypi

I am setting up my own PyPI containing some private packages. The problem is that some of the private packages have the same name as existing packages in PyPI.

The private packages with same name do not necessarily have higher version number than the existing packages in PyPI, therefore when I do `pip install --extra-index-url <Private_PyPI_URL>`, pip will automatically download the packages with higher version number which may not be the one from my private repository.

How can I make `pip install` check PyPI for packages only if it fails to find the package from the private repository?

Note also that the private packages can sometimes be specified as the dependencies of other private packages as well.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `--find-links` direct link to the index page listing those packages:

```
pip install --find-links <Private_PyPI_URL>/package_name package_name
```

but you *really* want to use an *internal* version number (append `_companyname_1`, etc.) and pin to those version numbers. See [Specifying Your Project’s Version](http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#specifying-your-project-s-version) in the Packaging Guide.

That way you can still switch between your version and the publicly released version *simply by switching version numbers*.

Another thing you want to do is use a proper [pip requirements file](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/requirements.html) to pin version numbers, and version-control that file. You can include indexes and find-links urls in that file too.

Comment: Unfortunately, the --find-links option doesn't work, pip will still end up installing the one with the higher version number...

Comment: The option with internal version number looks great, but I will need to specify the version everytime in order to choose the private package, is there a way to choose the private package first if the version number is not specified?

Comment: @Hery: Only if your version number is considered 'higher'. You may want to use a `requirements.txt` file instead, easier to specify a version pin that way.