# Python wheel anti-dependency

Tags: python, pip, dependencies, dependency-management, python-wheel

I'm managing a python project which can be released in two different variants, "full" and "lightweight", called e.g. `my-project` and `my-project-lw`. Both use the same top-level name, e.g. `myproject`. I have a script that cuts off the "heavy" parts of the project and builds both wheel installable archives with dependencies (the lightweight has considerably fewer). Everything works, and I can install them using the wheels.

Now I would like to make sure that a user wouldn't have both packages installed at the same time. Ideally I'd like pip to uninstall one when installing the other, or at least fail when the other is present (such that the user would have to uninstall the current manually).

Otherwise, when you install the `my-project` package it installs into `/lib/python3.6/site-packages/myproject`, and then when you install the `my-project-lw` package it overwrites the files in the same folder so you get a weird hybrid when some file are from "full" and some from "lightweigth", which is not good.

Is there a way to specify an anti-dependency? To mark them somehow as mutually exclusive? Thanks!

Comment: This might give you some ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17572783/private-pypi-containing-package-with-same-name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pip doesn't support it. See also the related 'obsoletes' metadata. https://github.com/pypa/packaging-problems/issues/154

Comment: That sounds like exactly the thing I need (the two packages "obsoleting" each other), I'll keep that in my sight! Thanks a lot!