# How do I ensure pip gets package from internal pypi?

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I have an application with a `requirements.txt` which includes a number of third party libraries along with one internal package which must be downloaded from a private pypi instance. Something like:

```
boto3
flask
flask-restplus
gunicorn
an_internal_package
```

The problem is that `an_internal_package` is named something quite common and occludes a package already available on the global pypi. For example, let's call it `twisted`. The problem I've run into is that setting `--extra-index-url` within `requirements.txt` seems to still grab `twisted` from the global pypi.

```
--extra-index-url=https://some.internal.pypi.corp.lan
boto3
flask
flask-restplus
gunicorn
twisted # actually an internal package
```

How can I indicate that `twisted` should be loaded exclusively from the private `pypi` and not from the global one?

Comment: The pragmatic solution is to rename the internal package to avoid the name collision.

Comment: [Finding Packages](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install/#finding-packages) from the PyPA states : `There is no ordering in the locations that are searched, rather they are all checked, and the “best” match for the requirements` - itreferences a PEP which seems to suggest that you need to fix this with versioning. ...  related- [Private PyPI containing package with same name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17572954/2823755) (answer).

Comment: @wim yes, i think you are 100% correct. as wwii indicates, pip provides almost no control over where packages are found.

Comment: If you can select the internal PyPI server, consider using `devpi` as it has a builtin spoofing protection - once you upload a package to the internal server, it stops looking for another versions elsewhere. You can thus upload `twisted` in the versions you need to `devpi`, use `--index-url` pointing to it and `devpi` will do the rest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could link directly to the package on your internal index instead:

```
boto3
flask
flask-restplus
gunicorn
https://some.internal.pypi.corp.lan/simple/twisted/Twisted-19.2.0.tar.bz2
```

This has the effect of pinning the dependency, but this is generally considered best practice anyways.

Comment: Note: this pins the version  (not necessarily a bad thing in a `requirements.txt` file, but worth mentioning).

Comment: @DustinIngram this seems very reasonable -- ideally, pinning the version would be optional. Do you know if a pypi rest api supports that?

Comment: It's not optional here because you're linking to a specific distribution to install. PyPI doesn't have a REST API, it has what's called the ["simple" API](https://warehouse.readthedocs.io/api-reference/legacy/#simple-project-api). I think what you're looking would be support from `pip` instead.

Comment: @DustinIngram a simple workaround for the version locking was to add a `latest` symlink on the internal `pypi`. Thus, I believe this should be the accepted solution. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -3):

You can refer [index](https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/1.1/requirements.html#indexes-find-links) for solution, its little tricky. you should be handling both private pypi and main pypi.

instead of using **--extra-index-url** you should be using **--index-url**. however read i recommend you to read through the given link

Comment: This has the same behavior as `--extra-index-url`, it changes the index for all the dependencies in the file, not just one.

Comment: I recommended  - **you should be handling both private pypi and main pypi**. now its the condition that he has to handle.